# Emoji are not being encoded correctly for output writer

Tags: java, json, utf-8, emoji

The program takes in a comment and persists it. The database stores the value correctly.( i'm able to copy and paste it into an emoji page and it shows up correctly). The string i see in the debugger on the postComment request and in the getAllComments response is the same, but it is sending {0xED, 0xA0, 0xBD, 0xED, 0xB8, 0x80 } instead of { 0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x80 } and showing up as several characters instead of 1. If i set the encoding to UnicodeBig the emoji show up in the response, but we need to be using UTF-8

```
String jsonString = jsonMapper.toJson(jsonResponse);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().println(jsonString);
```

Do i need to do something to these strings before having the system encode to utf8?
the libs used are

json-simple-1.1(current is 1.1.1)
jackson-core-2.2.3(current 2.6)

Thank you.

Comment: What is the JSON string you are expecting? Are these supposed to be code points? `{ 0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x80 }` It doesn't look like an emoji to me.  `U+00F0` is the Latin Small Letter Eth - ð.  The rest are [Unicode Control Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters).

Comment: should be the grinning face http://www.iemoji.com/view/emoji/885/people/grinning-face

Comment: it appears to be sending uD83D \uDE00 as if it were different characters

Comment: The correct way to express the Unicode code point `U+1f600` as a string in JSON is `"\uD83D\uDE00"`.

Comment: that is how it's showing up in java but but when being output it's sent as 0xED, 0xA0, 0xBD, 0xED, 0xB8, 0x80  instead of 0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x80. which is how it's being sent to the server in the first place.

Comment: I've taken the default bytes of the string then created a new string from the bytes and UTF-8 encoding and get the same string back. so it came in as UTF-8 4bytes why would it transmit as 6 bytes if the encoding didn't change?

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being an issue with Jetty 7. to get around this you can just .getBytes(String) and then write the bytes out and flush the buffer. Java will get the correct bytes and not encode the surrogate pair which is what Jetty was doing by default.