# Surrogate pairs not encoded correctly in HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, servlets

The issue is, if someone posts or makes a comment with an emoji or other character that uses surrogate pairs

```
private void writeJSONResponse(boolean hasApiVersion,HttpServletResponse response,JSONResponse jsonResponse) throws IOException{
    JsonMapper jsonMapper = new JsonMapper();
    String jsonString = jsonMapper.toJson(jsonResponse);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().println(jsonString);
}
```

i had posted this issue as
[Emoji are not being encoded correctly for output writer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879346/emoji-are-not-being-encoded-correctly-for-output-writer)
but didn't get any answers...

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f604/index.htm

it is being sent to the server as {f0 9f 98 84} but in the response it is encoded to {ed a0 bd ed b8 84}

The real funny thing is if i enable a gzip filter for the servlet the response is decoded correctly by clients.

THIS JUST IN!!!!!!
This works without using the gzip encoding fix...

```
private void writeJSONResponse(boolean hasApiVersion,HttpServletResponse response,JSONResponse jsonResponse) throws IOException{
    JsonMapper jsonMapper = new JsonMapper();

    String jsonString = jsonMapper.toJson(jsonResponse);

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    //response.getWriter().println(jsonString);
    byte[] bytes = jsonString.getBytes("UTF-8");
    response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
    response.getOutputStream().flush();

}
```

So... What is wrong/different with the way the Writer gets bytes from the  string vs getBytes?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Sean, if you want to merge this account with [your old account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5017303/sean-carlisle), please follow the steps here; http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: I'm not worried about losing credit for 1 question. i'm more worried about getting an aswer.

Comment: we are using jetty servlet-api-2.5 v6.1.9 so this bug may be the issue. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333481  but i have dependencies on dependencies on that older version so....